# Getting an @Embedded prefix annotation values from a @Relation parentColumn annotation in Room Android

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-room

Currently I have an Entity with a field of type class and annotated with @Embedded and prefixed.

```
class Foo{
...

@Embedded(prefix = "bar0_")
Bar bar0;

@Embedded(prefix = "bar1_")
Bar bar1;

...
}
```

In this class of this field annotated @Embedded, I have a @Relation annotated field denoting one-to-many relationships of a field of type `List<T>`.

```
class Bar{
...

String baz;

@Relation(parentColumn = "baz", ...)
List<SomeType> someTypeList

String barSpecificFields1;
String barSpecificFields2;
...
}
```

Since the both instances of `Bar` class are prefixed, this throws a compilation error denoting the column `baz` is not found (only `bar0_baz` or `bar1_baz` is available, and one at a time).
With this data structure, the only way I see how to solve this issue is to create 2 separate list with both `parentColumn` types. 
This seems wasteful as one  of the relation Entity will be unused in each instance but still be saved to DB, and I don't think this is the correct way.
Another possible way would be to somehow inject the prefix value to the `parentColumn`, but I'm not sure if this is even possible at all.

Am I encountering the limitation of Room because of how I mis-structured the data, and is there any other more efficient way to make this to work?

Comment: "This seems wasteful as one of the relation Entity will be unused in each instance " -- then why does `Bar` have the `@Relation`? Shouldn't `Foo` have the `@Relation`?

Comment: For example, there's a lot of other `Bar` specific fields such that it won't make sense from contextual level to move everything to `Foo` class. In my use case, putting @Relation in `Bar` promotes reusability and reduces duplication by half rather than putting both the @Relation in `Foo`.

Comment: "it won't make sense from contextual level to move everything to Foo class" -- I'm not suggesting move *everything* to `Foo`. I am suggesting moving the relation between `Foo` and `SomeType`.

Comment: Ah, ok. If I understand you correctly, that means we need to move both column name `baz` and `someTypeList` from the example above to the `Foo` class? This would work, would it be possible to have another workaround/solution to keep `baz` and `someTypeList` still in `Bar` class and have it work if for example both fields are specific to `Bar` class?

Comment: "that means we need to move both column name baz and someTypeList from the example above to the Foo class?" -- yes, if I am understanding your scenario correctly. "would it be possible to have another workaround/solution to keep baz and someTypeList still in Bar class and have it work if for example both fields are specific to Bar class?" -- not that I am aware of. IMHO, objects with Room annotations (entities and POJOs) should be treated as pure DTOs, with business logic on some other model class.